# MaterialUI horizontal forms

Tags: material-ui

I've been using react-bootstrap with bootstrap-material so far. However, I much prefer the API, as well as the overall simplicity of working with just material-ui. However, I'm currently developing an app that relies heavily in forms, and I would like to know if there is a way of making horizontal type forms, like in [bootstrap-material](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html#forms).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not built in but you could just use a standard label tag for each corresponding TextField. For color syncing and such though would need a bit more customization. Shouldn't be too tricky though.

Answer (score 9):

You may use flex positionning:

```
const flexContainer = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
};

return (
  <form style={flexContainer}>
    // TextFields here
  </form>
);
```